# Azure Pipelines condition doesnt work as it should

Tags: azure, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I started working with my YAML file to run some tasks and push a docker image in docker hub **IFF** branch is equal to master else run some tests and verify that tests passed without  problem I have this YAML file right now

```
trigger:
  - master


jobs:


  - job: runTests
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
      condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    steps:
      - task: Maven@3
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
          # according to: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3845,
          # maven options should go to goals instead, as mavenOptions is for jvm options
          mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
          javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
          jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
          jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
          publishJUnitResults: true
          testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
          goals: 'verify -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true --batch-mode --show-version'
  - job: ifBranchIsMaster
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
      condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    steps:
      - task: Maven@3
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
          # according to: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3845,
          # maven options should go to goals instead, as mavenOptions is for jvm options
          mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
          javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
          jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
          jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
          publishJUnitResults: true
          testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
          goals: 'verify -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true --batch-mode --show-version -Ddocker.username=$(DOCKER_HUB_USER) -Ddocker.password=$(DOCKER_HUB_PASS) docker:push'
```

so basically as we see in the documentation right [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) says exactly what condition to use in what situation and the

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```

works as it should when the branch is master run this steps else skip

but this condition

```
condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```

runs even in the master so what did I read wrong I want to skip the first tests if the branch is master cause if I don't skip the first one  I basically run the tests same tests 2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your indentation is wrong, it should be this:

```
  - job: runTests
    condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
```

Comment: o thank you very much that worked but why the second job runs if the branch is master? i mean it runs well as it should

Comment: because it has no condition (because your indentation is wrong), it always runs.

Comment: yes but i mean that `
- job: ifBranchIsMaster
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
      condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))` 
runs as it should only if its on master shouldnt that be wrong and tests run every time? even if its on other branch

Comment: yeah, sorry, its impossible to tell with this formatting, can you raise a new question if something else is wrong with the code?

Comment: well true the format isn't good well I don't think I should open a new question cause your answer helped a lot even with that cause I fixed what i wanted so nevermind thanks for your time